# Arranging several ggplots in same window

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created below `ggplots` in same window

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

x <- seq(0.01, .99, length.out = 100)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(x, 2),
  y = c(qlogis(x), 2 * qlogis(x)),
  group = rep(c("a","b"),
  each = 100)
)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
wrap_plots(A = p1, B = p2, C = p4, design = "AABB\n#CC#")
```

These generated below plot window

[image]

However now, I also want to squeeze my 3rd `ggplot` `p3` within the bottom-left white-space in the same window, without disturbing current structure.

Is there any way to achieve this. Any pointer will be very help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

x <- seq(0.01, .99, length.out = 100)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(x, 2),
  y = c(qlogis(x), 2 * qlogis(x)),
  group = rep(c("a","b"),
              each = 100)
)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))

layout <- "
AAABBB
CDDD##
"
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + 
  plot_layout(design = layout)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Or perhaps:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

x <- seq(0.01, .99, length.out = 100)
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(x, 2),
  y = c(qlogis(x), 2 * qlogis(x)),
  group = rep(c("a","b"),
              each = 100)
)
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))
p4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=group))

layout <- "
AAABBB
AAABBB
CDDD##
#DDD##
"
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + 
  plot_layout(design = layout)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>